# How can I make my XSLT template cope with missing parent elements?

Tags: xslt

I'd like to apologize for the poor title - I really didn't know how to phrase it any better. I'm currently working on an XSLT 1.0 script (using [xsltproc](http://www.xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html)) which transforms a simple XML format into a text representation suitable for consumption by an PDF generator.

In my XML format, there are just three elements: `<book>`, `<chapter>` and `<section>`.  However, due to some nasty feature of the DTD, I have a hard time writing a proper XSLT script to transform the document. Here's the DTD which describes their relation:

```
<!ELEMENT book ((chapter|section)*)>
<!ELEMENT chapter (section*)>
<!ELEMENT section (#PCDATA)>
```

Here's the my XSLT stylesheet which performs the translation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::section)">@BeginSections&#xa;</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>@Section @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:text>@End @Section&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::section)">@EndSections&#xa;</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::chapter)">@BeginChapters&#xa;</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>@Chapter @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:text>@End @Chapter&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::chapter)">@EndChapters&#xa;</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/book">
  <xsl:text>@Book @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:text>@End @Book&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, here comes the tricky part and my question: the DTD makes it possible to have `<section>` elements as the direct children of `<book>`. However, I still have to yield the same output as if that `/book/section` element was actually `/book/chapter/section`.

So e.g.: `<book><section/><chapter/></book>` becomes (I indented the output for better readability)

```
@Book @Begin
  @BeginChapters
  @Chapter @Begin
    @BeginSections
    @Section @Begin
    @End @Section
    @EndSections
  @End @Chapter
  @Chapter @Begin
  @End @Chapter
  @EndChapters
@End @Book
```

So what I'd like to do is to adjust my XSLT script so that the 'section' template somehow also calls the 'chapter' template in case the given `<section>` element is not within a `<chapter>`. How could I do this?

For what it's worth, here's another example. Multiple `<section>` elements which are not already in a `<chapter>` should get merged into one. Hence,`<book><section/><section/><section/><chapter/><section/></book>` yields output for three chapters (the first of which has three sections, the second has none, the third has one section).

Comment: Can't some form of or be used `<xsl:if test="chapter or section">, be used to math either chapter or section. After matching one of those, then proceed to match one or more sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="chapter|section" mode="chapter" name="makeChapter">
        <xsl:text>  @Chapter @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::chapter/node()[1]|
                                     self::section"
                             mode="section"/>
        <xsl:text>  @End @Chapter&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
             select="self::chapter/following-sibling::node()[1]|
                     self::section/following-sibling::chapter[1] "
             mode="chapter"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="section" mode="makeSection" name="makeSection">
        <xsl:text>    @Section @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>    @End @Section&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]/self::section"
                             mode="makeSection"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="section" mode="section">
        <xsl:text>    @BeginSections&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="makeSection"/>
        <xsl:text>    @EndSections&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="book/chapter|book/section">
        <xsl:text>  @BeginChapters&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="makeChapter"/>
        <xsl:text>  @EndChapters&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:text>@Book @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
        <xsl:text>@End @Book&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
@Book @Begin
  @BeginChapters
  @Chapter @Begin
    @BeginSections
    @Section @Begin
    @End @Section
    @EndSections
  @End @Chapter
  @Chapter @Begin
  @End @Chapter
  @EndChapters
@End @Book
```

**Note**: Fine grained traversal, grouping adjacents book/sections into one Chapter.

**Edit**: Corrected following sibling process for Chapters.

With this input:

```
<book>
    <section/>
    <section/>
    <section/>
    <chapter/>
    <section/>
</book>
```

Output:

```
@Book @Begin
  @BeginChapters
  @Chapter @Begin
    @BeginSections
    @Section @Begin
    @End @Section
    @Section @Begin
    @End @Section
    @Section @Begin
    @End @Section
    @EndSections
  @End @Chapter
  @Chapter @Begin
  @End @Chapter
  @Chapter @Begin
    @BeginSections
    @Section @Begin
    @End @Section
    @EndSections
  @End @Chapter
  @EndChapters
@End @Book
```

**Edit**: Better named templates to understand.

**Note**: Five rules: `book` rule "opens" a book and process first child; `book/section|book/chapter` rule (always the first because the fine grained transversal) "opens" book chapters, calls `makeChapter`; `makeChapter` rule, "opens" a chapter, process first child if context is `chapter` or self if context is `section` both in `section` mode, process next sibling if context is `chapter` or following `chapter` if context is `section` in `chapter` mode (meaning next chapter); `section` rule in `section` mode (because the node by node process, it will always match the first `sections` for adjacents `sections`) "opens" chapter sections an calls `makeSection` rule; `makeSection` rule "opens" a section an process childs, then process next sibling `section` in `makeSection` mode (this rule).

Comment: +1: Ah! This looks interesting. I'll try to understand it a bit and see whether I can extend it.

Comment: @Frerich Raabe: Explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

you need to first wrap the orphan sections into a single chapter..

we create a variable for this to hold the wrapped elements

```
<xsl:variable name="orphan">
  <chapter>
   <xsl:for-each select="/book/section">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </xsl:for-each>
  </chapter>
</xsl:variable>
```

then when you apply the templates inside the `/book` matching template you need to also use this newly created variable

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="chapter|exslt:node-set($orphan)"/>
```

and to use the `exslt` you need to add the namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
```

---

Final result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="orphan">
  <chapter>
   <xsl:for-each select="/book/section">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </xsl:for-each>
  </chapter>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::section)">@BeginSections&#xa;</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>@Section @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:text>@End @Section&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::section)">@EndSections&#xa;</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::chapter)">@BeginChapters&#xa;</xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>@Chapter @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:text>@End @Chapter&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::chapter)">@EndChapters&#xa;</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/book">
  <xsl:text>@Book @Begin&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter|exslt:node-set($orphan)"/>
  <xsl:text>@End @Book&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```